# Service design: where should I put my validation code?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, soa

I'm a little confused about the concept of services.

Let's assume i want to create a new user.
Right now, i'm checking if all fields are non-empty in Model (project.Web solution) and in UserServices too (project.Services solution). But to validate the email address i have to create a new function. 
Should i create that class in project.Services, something like GeneralValidation.cs and use it, or should i separate it from the Services and create a new project?

Until now i didn't create two solutions for Repositories and Services. I just had one solution for testing, other for project.Web, and another solution where i had the a domain folder, repository folder, and a few classes for business logic, but after reading a little about design patterns i've decided to split this.

Maybe i haven't understand yet the meaning of Services. For me, a service is a layer that will consume a repository (like user), and the service layer is where i should do the validation. If this is correct, that's why i don't know where to create the function for email validation for example.

If someone could explain me this i would really be appreciated. I've already read blogs articles, and search similar questions in stackoverflow but i can't be sure if i've really understand it.

Thanks

Comment: Make yourself a better title.  "Design Patterns" conveys no information about what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services and Repositories are 'first class citizens' in Domain Driven Design, so I do not see why you'd want to put them in a separate project ?

For your specific scenario, why don't you create a 'UserService' which has a method 'CreateUser', which looks for instance like this:

```
public static class UserService
{
    public static CreateUser( User u )
    {
         var userRepository = RepositoryFactory.CreateUserRepository();

         userRepository.Save (u);

         SendActivationMailForUser(u);
    }

    private static void SendActivationMailForUser( User user )
    {
         ....
    }
}
```

Some more information about services can be found [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, now i've the repositories and services in the same solution. 
That was a nice article you recommended me, thanks again.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511137/is-the-solution-design-optimal-c-sharp-3-tier ?